# How to get all nodes in Tree?

Tags: trees

What is the most efficient way to get the nodes of a `Tree`?

```
tree = Tree[1, {Tree[    2, {Tree[5, {Tree[12, None], Tree[13, None]}], Tree[6, None]}],    Tree[3, {Tree[7, {Tree[14, None], Tree[15, None], Tree[16, None]}],      Tree[8, None], Tree[9, None]}],    Tree[4, {Tree[10, {Tree[17, None], Tree[18, None], Tree[19, None]}],      Tree[11, None]}]}];

Sort@Reap[TreeScan[Sow, tree]][[2, 1]] (* this seems wrong *)
```

Desired output: `Range[19]`

**Follow-up:** is there a way to get `Annotate` to work on `Tree` to store data in each node?

Comment: Could you please mention the desired output for your example?

Comment: Are you aware that node `4` appears twice? Maybe you meant to use `Tree[1, {Tree[
   2, {Tree[5, {Tree[12, None], Tree[13, None]}], Tree[6, None]}], 
  Tree[3, {Tree[7, {Tree[14, None], Tree[15, None], Tree[16, None]}], 
    Tree[8, None], Tree[9, None]}], 
  Tree[4, {Tree[10, {Tree[17, None], Tree[18, None], Tree[19, None]}],
     Tree[11, None]}]}]`,

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher sure i'll use that

Comment: I don't know anything about the `Tree` data structure or if it's documented to work with `VertexList`, but it seems to.  `ContainsExactly[VertexList[tree][[All, 1]], Range[19]]` returns `True`.

Comment: @M.R after you edited your question, the following: `Sort@Reap[TreeScan[Sow, tree]][[2, 1]] == Range@19` yields `True`. Can I ask for two things: one can you verify that, i.e that I did not make any mistakes? Two, do you still want a solution different than `Sort@Reap[TreeScan[Sow, tree]][[2, 1]]`? Could you explain why? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `TreeGraph`+`VertexList`+`SortBy` is the most efficient for Breadth First Search:

```
tree = RandomTree[5000];
RepeatedTiming[n1 = Reap[TreeScan[Sow, tree, TreeTraversalOrder->"BreadthFirst"]][[2, 1]];]
RepeatedTiming[n2 = SortBy[VertexList[TreeGraph[tree]],#[[2]]&][[All,1]];]
RepeatedTiming[n3 = TreeLevel[tree, All -> "Data", TreeTraversalOrder->"BreadthFirst"];] 
RepeatedTiming[n4 = List @ TreeFold[{Sequence @@ #2 &, # &}, tree];] (* wrong *)
n1==n2==n3
Take[#,3]&/@{n1,n2,n3,n4}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The documented way using only Trees functionality is:

```
TreeLevel[tree, All -> "Data"]
```

Comment: This is the simplest, but doesn't seem to be the fastest. Also is the root missing? Length@TreeLevel[RandomTree[2], All -> "Data"] is 1 but should be 2.

Comment: @user5601 Length @ TreeLevel[RandomTree[2], All -> "Data"] gives 2 for me in 13.0.1, what version are you using?

Comment: A faster approach is List @ TreeFold[{Sequence @@ #2 &, # &}, tree]. TreeLevel itself could be sped up.

Comment: Thanks that does seem faster, but can you do BreadthFirst?

Comment: That TreeFold doesn't work at all for me... `tree=Tree[1, {Tree[2, None], Tree[3, {Tree[4, None], Tree[5, None], Tree[6, None]}], Tree[7, None]}];List @ TreeFold[{Sequence @@ #2 &, #&}, tree] (*{2,4,5,6,7}*)`

Comment: @user5601 There's not a straight forward way to get the data in a breadth-first order with TreeFold since it collects the data of parents and children in a bottom-up, depth-first order.

Comment: @M.R. Sorry, my previous comment incorrectly gives just the data of the leaves. lericr's answer Flatten@TreeFold[List,tree] gives the data of all nodes.

Comment: @IanFord That command is still does not work as BFS

Answer (score 1):

```
TreeLeaves[tree]
```

Or maybe

```
TreeCases[tree, _]
```

Or maybe

```
Flatten @ TreeFold[List, tree]
```

You might want to peruse http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ComputationOnTrees.html

Comment: Three points: `TreeLeaves` doesn't return the root nor does it strip the nodes out; TreeCases returns subtrees - not what I want; and TreeFold maintains the structure which is inefficient for large trees.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to traverse the tree and return every leaf, collecting them using Reap. E.g.:

```
Reap[
  TreeScan[Sow, tree]
][[2,1]]

(* {11, 12, 4, 5, 2, 13, 14, 15, 6, 7, 8, 3, 16, 17, 18, 9, 10, 4, 1} *)
```

Comment: that's was my starting point see above

Comment: @M.R. - then you had the answer all along!